# Bootstrap navbar collapsing issue when there are some non collapsed items.

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement a menu in a webpage with Bootstrap that has some items which are not collapsed in extra-small screens.

I've been able to do progress implementing it. When the screen is extra-small, the items I want to not collapse are working as they should. But the problem is when I click on the navbar-toggle button, the collapsed menu shows up only on the right side of the screen and it's not screen wide as it normally is.

How can I fix this issue?

```html
<nav role="navigation"   class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Projeto</a>
    </div>
    
    <!-- 'Sticky' (non-collapsing) right-side menu item(s) -->
    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
      <ul class="nav  navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li class="pull-left"><a href="contato.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> </li>
      </ul>
      
        <!-- Required bootstrap placeholder for the collapsed menu -->
      <button type="button" style="margin-left:20px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
        
    
     <!-- The Collapsing items            navbar-left or navbar-right -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">O Curso <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Sobre o Curso</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Disciplinas</a></li>
              </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="professores.html">Professores</a></li>
        <li><a href="laboratorios.html">Laboratórios</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding navbar-fixed-top with a margin to the top of the collapsed div.